# Vite with shared package

Tags: vue.js, npm, vite

I have several Vue projects, using a shared package with some shared components and code. I use vite as frontend tooling.

Vite works great when developing, picking up any change to source files and reflecting it immediately. But I can't get this to work with the shared code. I have tried using relative dependencies (`relative-deps` and `relative-deps watch`) which does recompile the shared package when there is a change, but vite does not seem to detect the change.

How do I use a shared package together with vite, so changes in the shared package is instantly picked up by vite?

Comment: How do you set up your development env? Do you install your shared package like an npm package with local linking? If so I'm afraid that there is no way for Vite to know when your package is changed. Try importing your package source file directly by the relative path and when you are done developing, switch it back to use the package name

Comment: @Duannx: Currently I install it as a npm package, but this is not a requirement for me, as long as the code can be shared between multiple vue frontends.

Comment: Since you want to share the code between projects so it should be installed as an npm package. But as I said above, in your development environment, you can just import it directly by the relative path to make vite hot reload on change

Comment: @Duannx: I use continuous integration, so I can't really manually switch back and forth between relative paths and package name. But perhaps it is possible to have separate configurations for dev and production build, but using the same code.

Comment: Did you try `server.watch` https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-watch

Comment: @Kalimah I could not get it to work, and https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8619 suggest it does not work. Have you gotten it to work?

Comment: @Dunnax will paths mapping in tsconfig in the package resolve correctly when importing from the package using relative paths?

Comment: @JacquesB I did not have experience with path mapping. What about creating a file to import and re-export your local module? In your CICD process, you can rewrite it with the correct package name.

Comment: @Duannx you can write this as an answer rather than as a comment

Comment: @JacquesB I've tested on a new, fresh Vite 4 + Vue 3 + TS and found that if you install your local package with the `npm link` Vite will detect the changes and do HRM by default. You don't need to do the relative path hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vite detects changes in a shared package and reflects them with these steps:

1. Use the `npm link` command to create a symlink between your shared package and your Vue projects. This will allow your Vue projects to reference the shared package as if it was installed directly.
2. In the shared package, make sure to export all components and functions that are intended to be used in your Vue projects.
3. In your Vue projects, import the shared package's components and functions using a relative path, like this:

```js
   import MyComponent from '../path/to/shared/package/MyComponent.vue'
   import { myFunction } from '../path/to/shared/package/myFunction.js'
```

4. Make sure to include the shared package as a dependency in your Vue project's `package.json` file, like this:

```js
    {
      "dependencies": {
        "shared-package": "0.1.0"
      }
    }
```

5. Finally, in your Vue project's `vite.config.js` file, use the `resolve.alias` option to map the shared package to the symlinked version, like this:

```js
    export default {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          'shared-package': '/path/to/shared/package'
        }
      }
    }
```

Changes to the shared package should be immediately picked up by Vite and reflected in your Vue projects.

Comment: I don't see how this answer should work on the production build. But the idea of the alias is pretty good. You can toggle the alias on the CICD process to point Vite to the correct package in each environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Node.js script to automate the linking of your shared package to your Vue projects. Here's an example of what the script might look like:

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

// Define the name of your shared package
const sharedPackageName = 'my-shared-package';

// Define the paths to your shared package and Vue projects
const sharedPackagePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared-package');
const vueProjectPaths = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../vue-project-1'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../vue-project-2'),
  // Add more Vue project paths as needed
];

// Link the shared package to each Vue project
vueProjectPaths.forEach((vueProjectPath) => {
  console.log(`Linking ${sharedPackageName} to ${vueProjectPath}...`);
  try {
    execSync(`cd ${vueProjectPath} && npm link ${sharedPackageName}`);
    console.log(`Successfully linked ${sharedPackageName} to ${vueProjectPath}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to link ${sharedPackageName} to ${vueProjectPath}: ${error}`);
  }
});

// Install the shared package dependencies in each Vue project
vueProjectPaths.forEach((vueProjectPath) => {
  console.log(`Installing ${sharedPackageName} dependencies in ${vueProjectPath}...`);
  try {
    execSync(`cd ${vueProjectPath} && npm install`);
    console.log(`Successfully installed ${sharedPackageName} dependencies in ${vueProjectPath}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to install ${sharedPackageName} dependencies in ${vueProjectPath}: ${error}`);
  }
});

// Build the shared package
console.log(`Building ${sharedPackageName}...`);
try {
  execSync(`cd ${sharedPackagePath} && npm run build`);
  console.log(`Successfully built ${sharedPackageName}`);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(`Failed to build ${sharedPackageName}: ${error}`);
}

// Watch the Vue projects for changes using Vite
vueProjectPaths.forEach((vueProjectPath) => {
  console.log(`Watching ${vueProjectPath} for changes...`);
  try {
    execSync(`cd ${vueProjectPath} && vite --watch`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to watch ${vueProjectPath} for changes: ${error}`);
  }
});
```

This script assumes that your shared package and Vue projects are located in the same parent directory, and that you have a build script in your shared package's package.json file that builds the shared code to a format that Vite can consume. The script links the shared package to each Vue project, installs the shared package dependencies in each Vue project, builds the shared package, and then watches each Vue project for changes using Vite.

To run the script, save it to a file (e.g. link-shared-package.js) and then run node link-shared-package.js from the command line in the directory where the script is located. Note that you may need to modify the script to fit the specific needs of your project.

Comment: Wouldnt that still requre to rebuild the shared package every time there is a change? I'm looking for a solution where a change in a file in the shared package will have effect immediately, just like in a regular vite project.