# How to Avoid Restarting Vite when Local Shared Library Changes?

Tags: npm, node-modules, svelte, vite

I am developing a web app and a library which will be shared with multiple projects in the future, using Vite as my dev server. In the app, I have installed the library with `npm install [local path to lib]`, which creates a symlink rather than copying the files. In theory, this allows me to edit the library code and have the change immediately reflected in the app. However, repackaging the library (using Svelte's packaging utility) causes the files in the library's dist folder to be deleted and recreated. This in turn causes the Vite dev server running in the app directory to complain that the lib files have disappeared, and it doesn't recover from this state after the library is repackaged and dist is recreated.

Restarting the dev server resolves the problem, but this process takes several seconds every time I make any change to the library code. I'm thus wondering if there is a way around this, either at the dev server level (e.g. getting Vite to recognize that the files have been recreated) or at the packaging level (e.g. by not blowing away the existing dev folder contents when repackaging).

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783337/vite-with-shared-package) may provide another solution, but the use of relative paths to import the components directly seems hacky to me since (a) my project shouldn't need to know the path to the library locally, and (b) symlinking in node_modules and then importing from the relative path seems redundant. However, I may have misunderstood something about that answer, so please correct me if I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't think you actually WANT a way around the restart, because your dev server will keep using the old version of your library. A feasible approach might be to get rid of the symlink and simply copy your library files over to the app directory on build. This will reload the app due to file changes, but the dev server should stay up.